# Is there a way to merge grey scale images (JPEG) in R to create 'RGB' channels?

Tags: r, machine-learning, rstudio, conv-neural-network, rgb

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to convert a single greyscale (JPG) image and convert them to 3 RGB channels on Rstudio.

Additionally, I have 3 different greyscale images that I want to merge together into each RGB channel so that I can feed into a Neural network.

I want to do this in R studio but I can't find sources anywhere to help :(

Thank you.

Comment: You have two questions it seems. 1) how to take a grayscale pixel and convert it to RGB. That will just repeat the grayscale value for each channel, right? 2) how to take three grayscale pixels and join them, treating each as one channel, right?

Comment: Hi Brian, Yes That is correct :)

Comment: For question 1 you want `image_convert` from the `magick` package. For question 2, I can't recall the function off the top of my head, but the documentation for that package is extensive.

Answer (score 1):

Play with this formula and come up with your own implementation.

Y'=0.299R'+0.587G'+0.114B'
Y' is just some greyscale pixel. Value of Y' ranges between 0 and 255. How convenient.

More info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

For each image you can do something like this:

```
pseudo-code:
LET RED [][] be a 2d array containing image red pixel values
For each pixel in image:
RED [x][y] = new RGB PIXEL(Image[x][y],0,0) //R,G,B
```

Do the same for all other pixels

Comment: Thank's I'll try this later today :)